# WP8 - Multiple concurrent WebClient calls

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, webclient

I'm trying to download data from an online RESTful-source for my Windows Phone 8 App. There's a total of about 700 calls, each downloading a json-string of variable length.
I keep running into TargetInvocationExceptions telling me that a http error 404 occured after about 65-80 calls (every subsequent call throws this exception), but only when I call the DownloadStringAsync methon inside my loop. Downloading the json-data each by itself works flawlessly, so the online source is available and the content isn't too large to handle either.
I guess I'm having a problem with execution time since, but I have found no way around this as of now and it still is only a guess. Open for any suggestions here.

This is my code (MainPage.xaml.cs):

```
namespace MyApp
{

    static MyViewModel ViewModel;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new MyViewModel();
        this.DataContext = ViewModel;
        GetData();
    }

    void GetData()
    {
        int id = 1;

        while (id <= 717)
        {
            GetJson(id++);
        }
    }

    void GetJson(int id)
    {
        string url = Connector.BaseURL + id + "/";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(AddModelToViewModel);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
    }

    void AddModelToViewModel(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string json = e.Result;

            MyModel Model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(json);
            ViewModel.Models.Add(Model);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());                
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewModel contains only an

```
ObservableCollection<MyModel> Models
```

bound to a ListView in the MainPage-View

I'm still new to Windows Phone programming, so please excuse bad style :)

Edit: It's definitely a thing of too many requests at once. Splitting the GetData() method up in chunks of 50 requests at a time, started from a button press works without problems. As stated in a comment below, I don't think that the server blocks my requests. Is there a limitation from the side of Windowsphone?

Console code that works:

```
    static int count = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 717; i++)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DL);
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(BaseURL + i + "/"));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void DL(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("#" + ++count + ": " + (e.Error == null ? "No error." : "Error!"));
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem comes from your app? The server could have some sort of anti-leech protection, detecting that you're sending an abnormally large number of requests in a short time and blocking your next requests

Comment: @KooKiz I just tried implementing the same code in a console application. In this case it works, so the server should be ok with many requests.